# Set cookie domain with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im taking the domain from the HTML of the page using jQuery:

```
domainUrl = $("p.domain").text();
```

for the purposes of testing:

```
<p class="domain">.vl3.co.uk</p>
```

Which is also the domain Im testing the script on.

This then give an alert containing the correct domain:

```
alert(domainUrl);
```

I want to the use that variable to set the domain in a cookie:

```
set_cookie('visible', 'no', 2020, 1, 1, '/', '+domainUrl+');
```

Here is the set cookie function:

```
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure ) {
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );
  if ( exp_y ) {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }
  if ( path )
    cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );
  if ( domain )
    cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );
  if ( secure )
    cookie_string += "; secure";
  document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
```

Why doesnt the cookie domain get set?

I think the problem is how im using the domainUrl variable when setting the cookie?

Comment: What does `domainURL` contain?

Comment: domainUrl contains .vl3.co.uk

Comment: and whats the domain where this script is running at?

Comment: You can just use `;domain` and it will set the CURRENT domain

Answer (score 5):

It should be:
set_cookie('visible', 'no', 2020, 1, 1, '/', domainUrl);

Pls, try this extension, it works, it comprises all that:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Then you only have to write:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'jquery.com' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery Annex library

I think this is the best way to get and set cookies using jQuery:

```
// cookie [writes and reads cookies]

//set cookie
$.cookie('kittencookie', 'fluffy', {expires : 7});

//get cookie
var kittenCookieValue = $.cookie('kittencookie');
```

For more details see [documentation](http://sschlapkohl.1337server.com/jqueryannex/?examples).